# PDF viewer with "n pages" in the screen and horizontal scrolling one page at the time

Tags: windows-10, firefox, pdf-viewer

I want to read clearly the pages of pdf files on my windows 10 computer.

I thought about buying a curved 32" monitor, with high enough resolution, like QHD or 4K. Then I thought about placing side by side 3 monitor with same resolution (three old 1680x1050 monitor that I already own) and using NVIDIA surround to merge them in a single big screen, like this setup [image]

Surely a cheaper solution.

1. Now I need a pdf viewer that can view an integer number of pages on the screen, equally distributed on the horizontal space of the screen, so no page will be cut between the monitor junction.
2. I want also the possibility to scroll one page at the time. I explain what I mean: if I am viewing pages 1 2 3, and I click on next, I want to see pages 2 3 4, not 4 5 6.

I tried several software. I found none with these exact features, two that are almost ok.

Okular. It has 1, not 2. Using overview mode, and with overview columns set to 3 it has the right view but can't scroll one page at the time. It "creates sets" of n (3 in my case) pages at the time and jump from a set to another without changing one page at the time.

[image]

Firefox built-in pdf viewer, based on pdf.js. It has 2, not 1. Using horizontal scrolling it scroll one page at the time. But it does not have the zoom option to "horizontally divide" the screen in three equal parts and put one page in each ones.

[image]

Do you know a pdf viewer that meets my needs? Or someone that has modified pdf.js to create a web pdf viewer with the "n pages in the screen" option?

Comment: PDF XChange can do it.
"Ribbon layout"

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I have installed PDF-XChange Editor. Using ribbon layout and continuous view I'm in the same situation as firefox built-in viewer. It shows horizontally multiple pages but doesn't fit an integer number of them in the screen. It puts them side by side so the one that is on the right it's cut.
https://i.imgur.com/krS5Jli.png